# Android Spinner stays empty after adding adapter

Tags: android, spinner, reload

) i need your help again.
I tried 2 hours to fix this problem, i googled a lot and looked for similar questions. I found a lot but nothing worked.

Here's my problem:
I fill a spinner from an ArrayList of "Plants".
Then i set an Adapter to this Spinner and finally a OnItemSelectedListener.
When i open the Activity the Spinner is empty. But he must have done anything because when i go back to Home Screen and open the App again (through the icon, not the task manager) the Spinner is correctly filled.
I can't just reload the activity cause then i stuck in an endless loop :(
I think the Spinner reloads after it comes to the OnStart Method. But i dont know how to go on now :(

Heres's my Code:

*public class entscheidungsbaum extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
private Spinner spAlter= null;
private Spinner spArt= null;
private Spinner spBlaetterrand= null;
private Spinner spBlaetterForm= null;
private Spinner spBlueten= null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entscheidungsbaum);

    final Activity activity = this;
    activity.setTitle("Pflanze eintragen");

    spAlter = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spAlter);
    spArt = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spArt);
    spBlaetterrand = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spBlaetterrand);
    spBlaetterForm = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spBlaetterform);
    spBlueten = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spBlueten);
    FillSpinner();



}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

public void onButtonClick (View Click) {
    switch(Click.getId()){
    default: return;
    case R.id.weiter: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, formular.class));
        return;
    }
}

public void FillSpinner(){

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra("plantbundle");
    ArrayList<Plant> plantlist = extras.getParcelableArrayList("plant");


    ArrayAdapter<Plant> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Plant>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,plantlist);
    spAlter.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    spAlter.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Plant plant = (Plant)spAlter.getSelectedItem();
    // Anzeigen
    toast_selec_plant(plant);

}
private void toast_selec_plant(Plant plant) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pflanze ausgewählt:" + plant.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}*

Edith found out:
The plantlist that i get from the intent is empty thats why the spinners stays empty too.
But when i go out of the app and go in again it works. Strange. If you have any hints you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys. I got it.
I can end this monolog now.
Just to tell the interested ones what my failure was:

In the Class which gives the Arraylist of plants to the entscheidungsbaum.class per intent was a failure. I had a Arraylist Variable defined at the top of the class and filled it in an extra Method.
But without refreshing the Activity the Arraylist stays empty until refresh.
So i just deleted the variable definition and rewrote the method to give the arraylist back. After that i directly sent it per Intent to my entscheidungsbaum.class. And it works ;)

Thanks anyway guys , u can delete or freeze this question :)